# UpdateCustomer - implementation in C++

Tags: c++, object-oriented, linked-list, classes

I am trying to write a program that does the following:

> The application will read the customer and book orders data from a
> data file “BookOrders.txt” and load them in a customer linked list,
> each customer object contains an order linked list. The program will
> allow user to place an order, update an order, cancel an order,
> checkout orders for one customer and print all customers and their
> orders. The data file should be updated after each transaction of
> orders.

And well, I'm trying to implement a function that allows me to update customer name (`UpdateCustomer(Customer& current);`),

Here is what I've done so far:

```
void
CustomerList::UpdateCustomer(Customer& current)
{
    bool found = false;
    nodeType<Customer> *location;

    searchCustomerByNameHelper(current.getCustomerName(), found, location);

    if (found) {
        location->info.getCustomerName();
        cout << "The customer is updated." << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "The customer is not found." << endl;
    }
    return;
}
```

**And I was wondering if this is a good way to do it? or if I have a better option that I could apply?**

Here is the "entire" program (I have added the link below with all the other files (headers): including OrderList.h, Order.h, etc..., just in case):

**CustomerList.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <cstdbool>

#include "CustomerList.h"


using namespace std;


ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const CustomerList& customer)
{
    customer.print();
    return (os);
}


void
CustomerList::AddCustomer(Customer& customer)
{
    insertLast(customer);
}


bool
CustomerList::searchCustomerByName(string searchName) const
{
    bool found = false;
    nodeType<Customer> *location;

    searchCustomerByNameHelper(searchName, found, location);

    return (found);
}


void
CustomerList::searchCustomerByNameHelper(string searchName,
    bool found, nodeType<Customer>* &current) const
{
    found = false;
    current = first;

    
    while (current != nullptr && !found) {
        if (current->info.checkCustomerName(searchName)) {
            found = true;
        } else {
            current = current->link;
        }
    }
}


Customer
CustomerList::getCustomerByName(string _name) const
{
    Customer n;
    return n;
}


void
CustomerList::UpdateCustomer(Customer& current)
{
    bool found = false;
    nodeType<Customer> *location;

    searchCustomerByNameHelper(current.getCustomerName(), found, location);

    if (found) {
        location->info.getCustomerName();
        cout << "The customer is updated." << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "The customer is not found." << endl;
    }
    return;
}


void
CustomerList::UpdateDataFile(ofstream& file)
{
    nodeType<Customer> *current = first;

    while (current != nullptr) {
        file << current->info.getCustomerName() << endl
             << current->info.getAddress() << endl
             << current->info.getEmail() << endl;
        current = current->link;
    }
    return;
}
```

**CustomerList.h**

```
#ifndef CUSTOMERLIST_H_INCLUDED
#define CUSTOMERLIST_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

#include "LinkedList.h"
#include "Customer.h"

using namespace std;


class CustomerList : public linkedListType<Customer>
{
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const CustomerList& customer);
    public:
        void AddCustomer(Customer& customer);
        bool searchCustomerByName(string searchName) const;
        void searchCustomerByNameHelper(string searchName,
            bool found, nodeType<Customer>* &current) const;

        Customer getCustomerByName(string _name) const;

        void UpdateCustomer(Customer& current);
        void UpdateDataFile(ofstream& file);
};

#endif // !CUSTOMERLIST_H_INCLUDED
```

**Customer.h**

```
#ifndef CUSTOMER_H_INCLUDED
#define CUSTOMER_H_INCLUDED

#include <string>
#include <cstdbool>

#include "Order.h"
#include "OrderList.h"

using std::string;
using std::ostream;


class Customer 
{
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&,  const Customer&);

    private:
        string name;
        string address;
        string email;
        OrderList orders;

    public:
        Customer();
        Customer(string _name, string _address,
             string _email, OrderList _orders);

        OrderList getOrders();
        void AddOrder(Order arg);
        void UpdateOrders(string arg, int n);
        void CancelOrder(string arg, int n);
        
        string getCustomerName();
        string getAddress();
        string getEmail();
        double checkoutOrders();
        
        bool operator==(const Customer& n) const;
        bool operator!=(const Customer& n) const;
        bool checkCustomerName(string _name);
};

#endif // !CUSTOMER_H_INCLUDED
```

**Customer.cpp**

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdbool>

#include "Customer.h"


using namespace std;


ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,  const Customer& obj)
{
    return (os);
}


Customer::Customer() : name(""), address(""), email("") { }
        
Customer::Customer(string _name, string _address,
         string _email, OrderList _orders) :
    name(_name),
    address(_address),
    email(_email),
    orders(_orders) { }


OrderList
Customer::getOrders()
{
    return (orders);
}


void
Customer::AddOrder(Order arg)
{
    return;
}
        
        
void
Customer::UpdateOrders(string arg, int n)
{
    return;
}
        
        
void
Customer::CancelOrder(string arg, int n)
{
    return;
}
        

string
Customer::getCustomerName()
{ 
    return (name); 
}


string
Customer::getAddress()
{ 
    return (address); 
}


string
Customer::getEmail()
{ 
    return (email); 
}


double
Customer::checkoutOrders()
{ 
    return (0.0); 
}

        
bool
Customer::operator==(const Customer& n) const
{
    return (name == n.name || address == n.address
        || email == n.email);
}


bool
Customer::operator!=(const Customer& n) const
{
    return (name != n.name || address != n.address
        || email != n.email);
}


bool
Customer::checkCustomerName(string _name)
{ 
    return(name == _name);
}
```

Link:

```
https://github.com/Jrchavez09/Book_Store_application
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I'd say is that it will help document your code if you make function arguments const references when you aren't changing them.  It might also help performance, but thats normally less important with modern machines :).

If you have a `using namespace std;` at the top of your code please remove it.  It defeats the purpose of namespaces.  It is always better to use std::string rather that string.  It will be less pain further down the line.  However I have noticed you are formatting the code a certain way, return values on a separate line, java style braces, bracketed return values, etc, so string might be part of your setup.

Its really trivial but why has `CustomerList::AddCustomer()` got a capital A?  (also the U in update is capitalized)  Consistency helps readability.

*IN MY OPINION* (and I'm not always right) I would say that you could implement `UpdateCustomer` to be clearer, easier to read and maintain.  The way you have done it looks 'odd', you are using out arguments rather than the function return value.  Out variables tend to produce bulkier code but it doesn't mean they are bad idea.

`CustomerList::searchCustomerByNameHelper()`: I think this function should be private function called `findByName`.

```
nodeType<Customer>* findByName (const string& searchName)
{ 
    nodeType<Customer>* iCurrent = first;
    while (iCurrent != nullptr 
       && !iCurrent->info.checkCustomerName(searchName) )
    {
        iCurrent = iCurrent->link;
    }
    return iCurrent; // Will be nullptr if the name is not found.
}
```

This means that `addName()` can check to see if the name already exists, because that will cause issues with your code as it is.  `searchByCustomerName` (which should really be called `doesNameExist`) could be stripped down to just one line:

```
bool
CustomerList::searchCustomerByName(const string& searchName) const
{
    return (nullptr != findByName (searchName));
}
bool
CustomerList::getCustomerByName(const string& _name, Customer& outValue) const
{
    const nodeType<Customer>* pResult = findByName(searchName);
    if (pResult)
        outValue = *pResult;
    // else Should really empty the outValue.
    return (pResult != nullptr);
}
bool
CustomerList::UpdateCustomer(Customer& current)
{
    const nodeType<Customer>* pResult = findByName(current.getCustomerName());
    if (pResult)
    {
        // Do your update 
    }
    return (pResult != nullptr);
}
```